# Is there a way to console.log an output only when my loop finishes running and matched no entry

Tags: javascript

In the code below how do i output try again only when the entire code execution runs and customer's order is not found amongst the product order in the menuItem dictionary.

I want to output this only when customer input doesn't match any product code

```js
let menuItem = {
  item_1: {
    name: "french burger",
    price: 1000,
    productCode: 101
  },
  item_2: {
    name: "chicken sharwama",
    price: 1500,
    productCode: 102
  },
  item_3: {
    name: "pizza",
    price: 5000,
    productCode: 103
  },
  item_4: {
    name: "beef sharwama",
    price: 1500,
    productCode: 104
  },
  item_5: {
    name: "smoothie (mix flavor)",
    price: 1300,
    productCode: 105
  }
}

listMenuItem = () => {
  for (let i in menuItem) {
    console.log(`Order Code: ${menuItem[i].productCode} || ${menuItem[i].name},  ${menuItem[i].price} NGN \n`)
  }
}

listMenuItem()
var order = prompt("Enter product code to make your order: ")
console.log(order)
let customerOrder = []

for (let i in menuItem) {

  if (menuItem[i].productCode == order) {
    customerOrder.push(menuItem[i])
    console.log(customerOrder)
    console.log(`${menuItem[i].name},  ${menuItem[i].price}`)
  } else {
    console.log("Product does not exist, try again")

  }
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to quote the grades and add the underscore in the if. Please take more care in writing code examples

Comment: [Loops and iterations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***Do some research***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: please i made edit to the question, can you help me look at it and offer the solution

Comment: Please click [edit] and then `[<>]` and create a [mcve] like I asked.

Comment: And read the links I gave you. [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure makes it harder to use the array methods.

The result is more confusing that it would have been if you just had an object keyed on productCode

```js
let menuItem = {
  item_1: {
    name: "french burger",
    price: 1000,
    productCode: 101
  },
  item_2: {
    name: "chicken sharwama",
    price: 1500,
    productCode: 102
  },
  item_3: {
    name: "pizza",
    price: 5000,
    productCode: 103
  },
  item_4: {
    name: "beef sharwama",
    price: 1500,
    productCode: 104
  },
  item_5: {
    name: "smoothie (mix flavor)",
    price: 1300,
    productCode: 105
  }
}

listMenuItem = () => {
  for (let i in menuItem) {
    console.log(`Order Code: ${menuItem[i].productCode} || ${menuItem[i].name},  ${menuItem[i].price} NGN \n`)
  }
}

listMenuItem()
var order = +prompt("Enter product code to make your order: "); // convert the string to number or make the productCode a string in the object
console.log(order)
let customerOrder = Object.entries(menuItem).find(([key,{productCode}]) => productCode === order);
console.log(customerOrder)
if (customerOrder) {
  console.log(`I found ${customerOrder[1].name},  ${customerOrder[1].price}`)
}
else {
  console.log("Product does not exist, try again")
}
```